# Triggering .html(result) in AJAX success part more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this code in my template (I have tried putting it before , but it doesn't help) to handle my ajax request:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#send-mail-button").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var nameVar        = $('#name').val();
            var emailVar       = $('#email').val();

            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>form/send",
                   data: { name          : nameVar,                    
                           email         : emailVar
                         },
                   success: function(result){
                      $('#form').html(result);
                   }

            });

            return false; 

        });


    });
</script>
```

And it works. The `#form` is replaced with the html from result as supposed. however, when I click on the `#send-mail-button` again. Nothing happens.

If I change the code to this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#send-mail-button").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var nameVar        = $('#name').val();
            var emailVar       = $('#email').val();

            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>form/send",
                   data: { name          : nameVar,                    
                           email         : emailVar
                         },
                   success: function(result){
                      alert(result);
                   }

            });

            return false; 

        });


    });
</script>
```

The form html is alerted in popup everytime. I am using the same template for the first formular and the same for the second. I have checked the source code and it's always the same (before and after click on button).

Any idea what is wrong with my javascript?

**UPDATE:**
My HTML:

```
<div id="form">

    <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

        <button type="button" id="send-mail-button">Send</button>

    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: you are probably replacing the `#send-mail-button` element, therefore the one with the bound handler no longer exists. use event delegation as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the element to which the click handler is destroyed when you replaced the form content.

Here you are dealing with the dynamic element after the first request is completed, so you need to use event delegation

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#form").on('click', '#send-mail-button', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var nameVar = $('#name').val();
        var emailVar = $('#email').val();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>form/send",
            data: {
                name: nameVar,
                email: emailVar
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#form').html(result);
            }

        });

        return false;

    });


});
```

Comment: Wow, it's working ;). I guess I need to check event delegation much more.